# How to integrate hosted blog into website

Tags: asp.net, blogs

I would like to integrate a **remotely hosted** blog into an existing ASP.net website.

I am *not* looking to host the blog platform itself because I would like to have a *low friction* solution where the users only have to concentrate on posting content and not maintain the blog engine.  (So I do not want to build a workpress, dasBlog, etc. blog engine on my servers.)

The old Blogger FTP solution is kind of what I am after.  What is the best way to accomplish this today?

My criteria:
- blog content is **updated** by users on a remote service (like blogger, etc.)
- blog content is **displayed** on my asp.net website with my website's look/feel/skin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually in the middle of doing the same thing right now. The solution I came up with was to use the Application Request Routing and URL Rewrite modules in IIS7. You can get started [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2010/04/02/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx), but there's a couple more things that you'll have to do to get everything working. If you're integrating the blog into an existing site you won't want your rewrite rules to apply sitewide, so surround your ruleset with the  element in the web.config and set it according to where you want the blog to appear on your site. Another thing that isn't addressed in Carlos's post is what to do about links that are referenced in CSS or javascript files, as they will not be rewritten. For those you will need an extra inbound rule that will pick up all of the relative urls that the first rewrite rule didn't get. You can look at the ruleset that I'm using (and maybe answer my question) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139733/problem-with-outbound-rules-when-setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-with-iis7-arr-url).
Hope this helps.